# Add coloured bullets to UI5 table using css based on column value

Tags: css, html, sapui5

I want to add coloured bullets to SAP UI5 table rows based on a particular column value. If the column has value > 50, then the bullet colour for that row should be blue, else green.
Please tell me how could we achieve that.

Comment: What do you mean by bullet? What control are you using for that?

Comment: A CSS bullet...I do not have any additional control. I just want a bullet to be added and the colur should be dynamic based on a column value.I am using SAP UI5 sap.m table and I want this feature for all its rows.

Answer (score 0):

use a formatter :)

```
<core:Icon size="1.5rem" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop sapUiSmallMarginBegin"
                       src="sap-icon://circle-task" //insert image of bullet here
                       color="{path: 'yourvalue', formatter: '.formatIconColor'}" />
```

something like this in the view.

and in the controller call the formatter for color and for image.

```
        formatIconColor:function(callf){
           switch(callf){
              case 'yourvalue>50': //something like this 
                 return "blue"; 

              default:
                 return "green";
           }//something like this
        },
```

probably the syntax is not exectly like this and you should use an if instead of the switch but the logic is this one.
Just include the sap icon inside your content and with the formatter you can control the color in base of your formatter function logic.

Comment: if you want css in the case yourvalue>50 for exemple you can do something like  item.$().find('.sapUiIcon').addClass('addbluetobullet'); and define the css class .addbluetobullet

Comment: The following code does not display any change - <ColumnListItem>
                          <cells >
                           
                           <core:Icon size="1.5rem" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop sapUiSmallMarginBegin"
                       src="sap-icon://circle-task"
                       color="red" /> 
                          </cells>
                      </ColumnListItem>...Am I missing something?

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/code this is how a column list should look like.